# Dynamically Adding Table Row

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder whether someone could help me please,

From a tutorial I found online which I've been able to adapt, I've put together the code below, which allows the user to dynamically add additional rows into a table following the insertion of data in the row above.

The problem I'm having is that I can only insert one more row, giving a total of two and I just can't find out why. I've been back to the original [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14995/Dynamically-add-and-remove-rows-in-a-HTML-table) to see check that my coding is the same and except for the changes in the field name, table name and the exclusion of the 'Add' button I can't see any differences to cause this problem.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps take a look at my code please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function addRow()
{
    //add a row to the rows collection and get a reference to the newly added row
    var newRow = document.all("addimage").insertRow();

    var oCell = newRow.insertCell();
    oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='radio' name='select'>";

    oCell = newRow.insertCell();
    oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='title'>";

    oCell = newRow.insertCell();
    oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='file' name='image'>";   
}

//deletes the specified row from the table
function removeRow(src)
{
    /* src refers to the input button that was clicked. 
       to get a reference to the containing <tr> element,
       get the parent of the parent (in this case <tr>)
    */   
    var oRow = src.parentElement.parentElement;  

    //once the row reference is obtained, delete it passing in its rowIndex   
    document.all("addimage").deleteRow(oRow.rowIndex);  

}
</script>
```

**Table Layout**

```
<table id="addimage" style="table-layout:auto">
   <tr>
      <td width="20"><input name="select" type="radio" id="select"/></td>
      <td width="144"><input name="title" type="text" id="title"/></td>
      <td width="304"><input name="image" type="file" id="image" onchange="addRow();"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try using `onclick` instead of using `onchange`. If possible post your complete code on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: See this: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/03/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript.html It also contains a live demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new row that you are adding do not have the onchange property set, it should be:

```
oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='image' onchange='addRow();'>";
```

Also, document.all("addimage") is (as far as i know) bad practice because it is not supported by all browsers. For compatibility you should also add index to insert the row in (-1 for last) and the index for the new cells. The parameter is required in Firefox and Opera, but optional in Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari. I suggest that you change your code to something like the following:

```
function addRow()
{
    //add a row to the rows collection and get a reference to the newly added row
    var newRow = document.getElementById("addimage").insertRow(-1);

    var oCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='radio' name='select'>";

    oCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
    oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='title'>";

    oCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
    oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='image' onchange='addRow();'>";   
}
```

Comment: Hi, that's absolutely brilliant thank you so much. I know that this is a slight deviation from my original post, but would I use the index number as a way of deleting a row? Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Seen the actual code. In that there is a button, when clicked, adds row to the table. In your case you are using `onchange` event. Instead of that use `onclick` event, as I mentioned in the comment.

Secondly, if you add `onclick` on every image, you will end up adding extra row on any image click. I hope it's okay for you.

**Suggestion**

Instead of using `onclick` on image use  `anchor` tag which contains your image or use single button as shown in the demo. It will look something like this

```
<table id="addimage" style="table-layout:auto">
 <tr>
   <td width="20"><input name="select" type="radio" id="select"/></td>
   <td width="144"><input name="title" type="text" id="title"/></td>
   <td width="304">
      <a href='#' onclick='addRow();'>
        <input name="image" type="file" id="image"/>
      </a>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
function addRow()
{
   //add a row to the rows collection and get a reference to the newly added row
   var newRow = document.all("addimage").insertRow();

   var oCell = newRow.insertCell();
   oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='radio' name='select'>";

   oCell = newRow.insertCell();
   oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='title'>";

   oCell = newRow.insertCell();
   oCell.innerHTML = "<a href='#' onclick='addRow();><input type='file' name='image'>'</a>";   
}
```

If you want to disable the anchor tag after row is added you can disable it using javascript.
Hope this works.

Comment: Hi, this is great, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post and for your help. Kind regards